# how to set Oracle connection pool size?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, connection-pooling

We have been getting this Oracle connection pool exception a lot recently for our ASP.NET website. This is the detailed exception message:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may
>   have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool
>   size was reached.

This is our connection string

```
User ID=user1;password=password1;DATA SOURCE=Datasource1
```

Can you tell me how to set max pool size to **1** so that I can debug it on my local?

Another question is: what is the recommended pool size for a website with 10,000 users? and if max pool size is reached, how to fail gracefully?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used such connection string to set the connection pool size:

```
const string connString = "server=localhost;" +
                              ....
                             "Min Pool Size=3;" +
                             "Max Pool Size=3";
```

But you don't need to set connection pool size bigger. Such error message I have got when I  forget to close connections.  Check your code to find places where you open connections, but don't close them.  [It can help you](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040830.htm).

Comment: I know it. I have written about Oracle.